# Remove Elements from fullcalendar (by dragging to trash can)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar with external elements being dragged onto it.  I'm relatively new to jquery.  I don't know quite how to get the ID of the object being dragged to a "trash can" icon.  I simply want to drag items off of the calendar to a image and when I let go of the mouse the item is removed.

This is my code.....

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../fullcalendar.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='../jquery/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../jquery/jquery-ui-custom.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {


        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);



            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });




        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;



                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();

                }
            }

        });

    });

</script>
<style type='text/css'>

    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

    #wrap {
        width: 1100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

    #external-events {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #eee;
        text-align: left;
        }

    #external-events h4 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 1em;
        }

    .external-event { /* try to mimick the look of a real event */
        margin: 10px 0;
        padding: 2px 4px;
        background: #3366CC;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: .85em;
        cursor: pointer;
        }

    #external-events p {
        margin: 1.5em 0;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #666;
        }

    #external-events p input {
        margin: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        }

    #calendar {
        float: right;
        width: 900px;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='wrap'>

<div id='external-events'>
<h4>Draggable Events</h4>
<div class='external-event'>even1</div>
<div class='external-event'>even2</div>

<p>
<input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' /> <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
</p>
</div>

<div id='calendar'></div>

<img src="redmond/images/trash.png" id="trash">

<div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am trying to accomplish the same thing. I have tried Agzam's suggestion, and that does allow you to drag items off the calendar, but I cannot seem to figure out the correct way to detect this behavior is "abnormal" in order to trigger the delete event.

Answer (score 20):

**Complete tutorial, how to add "move to trash" function to fullcalendar**

[image]

[HERE IS DEMO](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33338943/fc/index.html)

if you do not want to use droppable:

from fullcalendar.css delete this lines

```
.fc-view
 {
   /* prevents dragging outside of widget */
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

find in fullcalenar.js (line cca 6086)

```
function eachEventElement(event, exceptElement, funcName) {
    var elements = eventElementsByID[event._id],
        i, len = elements.length;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (!exceptElement || elements[i][0] != exceptElement[0]) {
            elements[i][funcName]();
        }
    }
}
```

and change to:

```
function eachEventElement(event, exceptElement, funcName) {
    var elements = eventElementsByID[event._id],
        i;
    if (elements != null) {
        var len = elements.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (!exceptElement || elements[i][0] != exceptElement[0]) {
                elements[i][funcName]();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in js:

```
//actually cursor position
var currentMousePos = {
    x: -1,
    y: -1
};

//set actually cursor pos
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(document).on("mousemove", function (event) {
        currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
        currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
    });

});

//check if cursor is in trash 
    function isElemOverDiv() {
        var trashEl = jQuery('#calendarTrash');

        var ofs = trashEl.offset();

        var x1 = ofs.left;
        var x2 = ofs.left + trashEl.outerWidth(true);
        var y1 = ofs.top;
        var y2 = ofs.top + trashEl.outerHeight(true);

        if (currentMousePos.x >= x1 && currentMousePos.x <= x2 &&
            currentMousePos.y >= y1 && currentMousePos.y <= y2) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

//fullcalendar mouseover callback

        eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent) {
            $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
                var trashEl = jQuery('#calendarTrash');
                if (isElemOverDiv()) {
                    if (!trashEl.hasClass("to-trash")) {
                        trashEl.addClass("to-trash");
                    }
                } else {
                    if (trashEl.hasClass("to-trash")) {
                        trashEl.removeClass("to-trash");
                    }

                }
            });
        },

//fullcalendar eventdragstop callback
eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    if (isElemOverDiv()) {

        jQuery('#fr-calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);

        var trashEl = jQuery('#calendarTrash');
        if (trashEl.hasClass("to-trash")) {
            trashEl.removeClass("to-trash");
        }
    }
},
```

in fullcalendar set option  dragRevertDuration: 0,

in fullcalendar declaration add loading callback function for append a trashcalendar:

```
loading: function (bool) {
    if (!bool) {
        jQuery('.fc-header-left').append('<div id="calendarTrash" class="calendar-trash"><img src="' + imagePath + '/cal-trash.png"></img></div>');

    }
},
```

css for trash:

```
div.calendar-trash{
float: left;
padding-right: 8px;
margin-right:5px;
padding-left:8px;
padding-top: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.to-trash{
  background-color:#EAEAEA;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5em;
    border-radius: 5em;
}
```

If loading callback not working, add trash on end of jquery document ready function.

```
foo.JFS('.fc-header-left').append('<div id="calendarTrash" class="calendar-trash"><img src="/images/cal-trash.png"></img></div>');
```

trash icon:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

first of all you're gonna need to remove overflow statement from css:

```
 .fc-view
 {
   /* prevents dragging outside of widget */
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

then you can use [eventDragStop](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDragStop/)

Answer (score 1):

here is something I just did hope it helps. I dont know if you are using php/mysql but if your not just remove the ajax call and keep what is in the success function.

```
        $('#calendar').children('.fc-content').children().append('<div id="calendarTrash" style="float: right; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span></div>');

    //listens for drop event
    $("#calendarTrash").droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function(event, ui) { 
            if ( dragged && ui.helper && ui.helper[0] === dragged[0] ) {
                var event = dragged[1];
                var answer = confirm("Delete Event?")
                if (answer)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'/employees/removeevent?id='+event.id,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: false,
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                        {
                            //console.log(xhr.status);
                            //console.log(thrownError);
                        },
                        success: function()
                        {
                            calendar.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' , event.id  );
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

        eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
            dragged = [ ui.helper[0], event ];
        },
```

Comment: the event from the calendar.

Comment: ok it has been a long time but if found the code. I will edit the post but what it is doing is just storing in an array the different components needed.

Comment: Thanks. It works very well. I would have preferred the trash icon in the header right, but I only could place it on the bottom right... However it' s ok...

Comment: You should be able to move it wherever you want. I could be wrong but I think the only reason it is in the bottom right is because that is where I put it. You should just be able to change what it is appending to and mess with some css.

Comment: Yes, of course I suppose it's possible, but it's not as easy as one could expect... Appending "#calendarTrash" div to the fullcalendar top-right div (now I can't remember how it's named...) puts the div in the top right position, but it looses it's "droppablility"... If you happen to solve this isuue, please let me know here, though I can live with the trash in the bottom, too... :-)

Answer (score 0):

i tell us drop: function(event, ui) ui :: ui holds an empty object. Before version 2.1, the jQuery UI object. :) and work then jsEvent :) sn :

```
eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view) {

       if (isElemOverDiv(jsEvent, $('div#external-events'))) {

           console.log(isElemOverDiv(jsEvent, $('div#external-events')));
           $('.calendario').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
       }
   }

  var isElemOverDiv = function(draggedItem, dropArea) {
  var p = dropArea;
  var position = p.position();
  console.log("EL DROP AREA left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top);
  console.log('draggedItem.pageY ', draggedItem.clientX, draggedItem.pageY);
  if (draggedItem.clientX >= position.left && draggedItem.pageY >= position.top) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
 <div id="calendarTrash" class="calendar-trash"><img src="images\trash.png"  alt="image"/></div>


 ` eventDragStop: function(event,jsEvent) {

        var trashEl = jQuery('#calendarTrash');
        var ofs = trashEl.offset();

        var x1 = ofs.left;
        var x2 = ofs.left + trashEl.outerWidth(true);
        var y1 = ofs.top;
        var y2 = ofs.top + trashEl.outerHeight(true);

        if (jsEvent.pageX >= x1 && jsEvent.pageX<= x2 &&
            jsEvent.pageY >= y1 && jsEvent.pageY <= y2) {
                if (confirm("Are you sure to  detete " + event.title +" ?")) {
                    //pour annuker les informations
                    $('#external-calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                }

        }
    }
```