# Delete event by dragging it outside of the full calendar V 2 (with or without trash icon...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fullcalendar

Can somebody please give me advice on how to delete events from the FullCalendar Version 2 by dragging it out of the calendar, please?

I saw some solution here: [Remove Elements from fullcalendar (by dragging to trash can)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470154/remove-elements-from-fullcalendar-by-dragging-to-trash-can)

but it seems to address the version 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Elements from fullcalendar (by dragging to trash can)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470154/remove-elements-from-fullcalendar-by-dragging-to-trash-can)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My first approach would be:

```
eventDragStop: function(event,jsEvent) {
    alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
    if( (300 <= jsEvent.pageX) & (jsEvent.pageX <= 500) & (130 <= jsEvent.pageY) & (jsEvent.pageY <= 170)){
      alert('delete: '+ event.id);
      $('#MyCalendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
    }
}
```

This allows to drag events to the area (in pixels) corresponding to the if condition order to delete. Tested with fullcalendar 2.1.1.

An improvement would be to check and compare jsEvent coordinates with `$(window).height()` and `$(window).width()`, this way would confirm/test dragging out of calendar area, much neat of course.

Actually the improvement is (an elegant solution), based on the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470154/remove-elements-from-fullcalendar-by-dragging-to-trash-can) mentioned:

1. Create a div element with the icon trash:

> ```
> <div id="calendarTrash" class="calendar-trash"><img src="path/to/static/images/trash.png" /></div>
> ```

2. The eventDragStop is:

   ```
   eventDragStop: function(event,jsEvent) {

       var trashEl = jQuery('#calendarTrash');
       var ofs = trashEl.offset();

       var x1 = ofs.left;
       var x2 = ofs.left + trashEl.outerWidth(true);
       var y1 = ofs.top;
       var y2 = ofs.top + trashEl.outerHeight(true);

       if (jsEvent.pageX >= x1 && jsEvent.pageX<= x2 &&
           jsEvent.pageY >= y1 && jsEvent.pageY <= y2) {
           alert('SIII');
           $('#calendario').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
       }
   }
   ```

Tested on Fullcalendar 2.1.1

Comment: Works great. Thanks. I just had to change event.id to event._id

Comment: I did it with an external trash-div where events can be dragged to for removing them. Why doesn't it work with jQueryUi jsut making the trash-div.droppable. The fullCalendar events are not even recognized when being dragged over a droppable, why?

Comment: This works for me except that before it is deleted it shows the animation of the event going back to its original date.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: @skeletank check out dragRevertDuration property - http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/dragRevertDuration/ for preventing animation.

Comment: Worked Great! Thank you @user2155441

Comment: @RredCat Thanks, it works. I set it to 0: "dragRevertDuration: 0"

Comment: @RredCat did you set dragRevertDuration for the event only if it was placed on the trash? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Without jQuery :

```
        eventDragStop: function(e) {
            let trashEl = document.getElementById('fcTrash') //as HTMLElement;

            let x1 = trashEl.offsetLeft;
            let x2 = trashEl.offsetLeft + trashEl.offsetWidth;
            let y1 = trashEl.offsetTop;
            let y2 = trashEl.offsetTop + trashEl.offsetHeight;

            if (e.jsEvent.pageX >= x1 && e.jsEvent.pageX <= x2 &&
                e.jsEvent.pageY >= y1 && e.jsEvent.pageY <= y2) {
                    e.event.remove();
            }
        }
```

Comment: should also comment that this is the way to do this with latest version (5.0) of fullcalendar (there is only 'info' that comes from the function, no longer two variables - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDragStop)

Answer (score 1):

```
 eventDragStop: function(event,jsEvent) {

        var trashEl = jQuery('#calendarTrash');
        var ofs = trashEl.offset();

        var x1 = ofs.left;
        var x2 = ofs.left + trashEl.outerWidth(true);
        var y1 = ofs.top;
        var y2 = ofs.top + trashEl.outerHeight(true);

        if (jsEvent.pageX >= x1 && jsEvent.pageX<= x2 &&
            jsEvent.pageY >= y1 && jsEvent.pageY <= y2) {
                if (confirm("Are you sure to  detete " + event.title +" ?")) {
                    //pour annuker les informations
                    $('#external-calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                }

        }
    }
```

`
**event._id** not  event.id (all events will be deleted)

```
<div id="calendarTrash" class="calendar-trash"><img src="images\trash.png"  alt="image"/></div>
```