# An elegant way to install a trash can to delete full calendar events in Smart Admin Theme?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, smartadmin

I am working with the [Smart Admin Theme](https://bootstraphunter.com/smartadmin-product.php) and I wanted a way to install a trash can on the calendar page so that I can let the users easily drag and drop the events to remove them.

I have gone through [Remove Elements from fullcalendar (by dragging to trash can)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470154/remove-elements-from-fullcalendar-by-dragging-to-trash-can) and although I appreciate eXistPierre's answer and a few others, they are definitely well written but there were still a few problems I faced. They are almost 2 years old and they are probably for an older version of full calendar. Moreover since I am not a seasoned Javascript develoepr and still learning, I couldn't relate to the code.

I am answering a way to install a trash can which is inspired by eXistPierre but conforms to a newer version and is much simpler, at least in my opinion. I hope this would help anyone else working with Smart Admin Theme who also may want to install a trash can to remove events from calendar.

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you have tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the events cannot be dragged outside the calender. To enable that:

```
.fc-view
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

This will allow the users to drag events outside the calendar.

Secondly I installed a small div with a trash can on the left side of the calendar where new events can be created with the following code:

```
<div class="well well-sm" id="deleteEventsDiv">
    <legend>
        Delete Events
    </legend>
    <img src="/img/avatars/cal-trash.png">
    <div class="note">
        <strong>Note:</strong> Drag and drop events here to delete them
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the `eventDragStop` method to listen to when the drag event stops. I have used simple Jquery to check if the drop was over the trash can div and if yes the ajax call to the web service would fire depending on the confirmation popup which is also a part of the Smart Admin Theme.

```
eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view, removeEvents ) {
    // This condition makes it easier to test if the event is over the trash can using Jquery
    if($('div#deleteEventsDiv').is(':hover')){
        // Confirmation popup
        $.SmartMessageBox({
            title : "Delete Event?",
            content : 'Are you sure you want to remove this event from the calender?',
            buttons : '[No][Yes]'
        }, function(ButtonPressed) {
            if (ButtonPressed === "Yes") {

                // You can change the URL and other details to your liking.
                // On success a small box notification will fire
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/events/' + event.id,
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    success: function(request) {
                        $.smallBox({
                            title : "Deleting Event",
                            content : "Event Deleted",
                            color : "#659265",
                            iconSmall : "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                            timeout : 4000
                        });
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
},
```

And that's it. You're good to go. The trash image is also included with this answer and a screenshot of the div.

Trash can png:

[image: Trash can image]

Screenshot of trash can `div`:

[image: Screenshot]